# Query with join table bringing wrong ID - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This is driving me crazy.

I have two tables: Records and Users and a query to bring records of users:

```
$records = Record::with('user')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'records.user_id')
        ->orderBy('users.name', 'asc')
        ->where('schedule_id', $schedule->id)
        ->get();
```

The `dd($records);` brings me this:

```
Collection {#827 ▼
    #items: array:6 [▼
        0 => Record {#773 ▼
            #connection: "mysql"
            #table: null
            #primaryKey: "id"
            #keyType: "int"
            +incrementing: true
            #with: []
            #withCount: []
            #perPage: 15
            +exists: true
            +wasRecentlyCreated: false
            #attributes: array:13 [▼
                "id" => 26
                "user_id" => 26
                "schedule_id" => 3
                "start_time" => "12:00"
                "end_time" => "20:00"
                "created_at" => null
                "updated_at" => null
                "name" => "Ali Fay"
                "email" => "twolff@gmail.com"
                "password" => ""
                "role_id" => 6
                "store_id" => 3
                "remember_token" => null
            ]
```

As you can see, the attributes are ok of both models except the "id", that is the id of the user, not the record. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: may be it correct ! check in the data base to see if the records has the same id as the user ;)

Comment: they dont have same ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `join()` here:

```
$records = $schedule->records()->with('user')->get();
```

Then sort the collection:

```
$records->sortBy(function($i) {
    return $i->user->name;
});
```

Comment: schedule_id is the records table, not users :(

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.name' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `records` where `schedule_id` = 3 order by `users`.`name` asc)

Comment: @Poxxac what exactly doesn't work? Do you get an error or something? Also, the second one is `sortBy()` not `orderBy()` and it's not a query, you're working with collection here.

Comment: no, the order of the result is by id of records, not by name of users

Comment: @Poxxac don't use `orderBy()`, just copy-paste my code. I've just tried and it works for me with the same `belongsTo` relationship.

Comment: [Relationship](https://ibb.co/dS9hrm) | 
[Query](https://ibb.co/hYHDxR) | 
[Result](https://ibb.co/iM8aBm)

Comment: @Poxxac that's because you don't save results of sorting. You you don't want to use it right away, you need to save it with something like `$sorted = $records->sortBy(.....);`

Comment: I feel stupid, I just added a "$records = " at the beginning and now it works hahaha xD

Comment: I'm marking this as answer because is the one I'm gonna be using, however @martin-henriksen final answer worked too

Answer (score 6):

The concrete problem is this case, that you have two columns named id in the join, so select the columns you need and only select one of the ids, can probaly easily be solved by this, and if columns of the user is needed you can select them as wanted.

```
$records = Record::with('user')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'records.user_id')
    ->orderBy('users.name', 'asc')
    ->where('schedule_id', $schedule->id)
    ->select('records.*')
    ->get();
```

The best solution is to use relationships, so if the `model` is something similar to.

```
public class record
{
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Then you instead can do the same query as. `WhereHas` checks if the relation with the given condition exists, otherwise if there was no condition, `has` could have been used.

```
Record::whereHas('user', function ($query) use($schedule){
    $query->where('schedule_id', $schedule->id);
})->get()->sortBy(function($item, $key) {
    return $item->user->name;
});
```

Comment: Not to conclude that this is the best solution, but in this concrete question this is the problem, i would go with adding a relationship thou.

Comment: Wow!, this worked, thanks!!  I'm running tests to see if there is something missing/broken because of the new query

Comment: yes, but if you need data from the user table, you can add it to ->select('records.*', 'users.importantColumn').

Comment: I just wanted to understand this now: With the "select" there, the result of the query is just the record object attributes, which has a relationship with an user object and I can still access to the user attributes by association on blade. Is that right?

Comment: yes, but there is a better way to do it, editing my answer.

Comment: Your second solution worked but not ordered by name of user. But thanks to your solutions, I'm understanding more about relationships in laravel, thanks  tho

Comment: read the docs and different answers and combine :) edited solution and should work now.

Comment: It worked great! I'm marking the other answer because it works too with less code and in the one I'm gonna be using. Thanks so much tho for the help

Comment: thats fair, but the other answer does not take schedule into consideration which where in the original question.

Comment: What if you want to join a query that has already been "composed" with a relationship dynamically? You can't start from `static::with`, you got a query object.